# How can I use Pandas to format individual cells conditionally in Excel?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['long', 'short', np.nan], 'b': [np.nan, 3, 2]})
```

I want to style the output of `df.to_excel`. Like this:

[image]

If `df.a == 'long'`, `a` is green and if `df.a == 'short'`, `a` is red.
I have read multiple posts on SO but couldn't figure out how to do it.

This is one of my attempts that got really close to the result:

```
def bounded_highlights(df):
    conds = [df.a == 'short', df.a == 'long']
    labels = ['background-color: pink', 'background-color: lime']
    array = np.select(conds, labels, default='')
    return array
```

When I used `df.style.apply(bounded_highlights, axis=None).to_excel(...` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `apply` passes `Series` to your function and you need to define what needs to be done to label your column. Here is a possible solution :

```
def bounded_highlights(s):

    if s.name=='a': # if column a is passed
        conds = [s == 'short', s == 'long']
        labels = ['background-color: pink', 'background-color: lime']
        array = np.select(conds, labels, default='')
        return array

    else: # if other columns are passed
        return ['']*s.shape[0]
```

Then use it this way :

```
df.style.apply(bounded_highlights).to_excel('file_name.xlsx')
```