# How can I conditionally change background color and font color of a cell when using Pandas to_excel?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [2, 2, 2, -4, np.nan, np.nan, 4, -3, 2, -2, -6],
        'b': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6]
    }
)
```

I want to change background color and font color of cells only for column `a`. For example, if `df.a > 0` background color is green otherwise it is red.

This code does that:

```
def highlight_cells(s):
    if s.name=='a':
        conds = [s > 0, s < 0, s == 0]
        labels = ['background-color: lime', 'background-color: pink', 'background-color: gold']
        array = np.select(conds, labels, default='')
        return array
    else:
        return ['']*s.shape[0]

df.style.apply(highlight_cells).to_excel('df.xlsx', index=False)
```

But I don't know how to add font color to that. I can add the same conditional with `color` property and repeat these lines but I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Pandas to format individual cells conditionally in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971878/how-can-i-use-pandas-to-format-individual-cells-conditionally-in-excel)

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I want to change background color AND font color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can add font colors as a list to the function too:

```
def highlight_cells(s):
    if s.name == 'a':
        conds = [s > 0, s < 0, s == 0]
        background_labels = ['background-color: lime', 'background-color: pink', 'background-color: gold']
        # desired font colors
        font_labels = ['color: white', 'color: white', '']  # Add font color labels
        background_array = np.select(conds, background_labels, default='')
        font_array = np.select(conds, font_labels, default='')  # Apply font color
        return [f'{b}; {f}' for b, f in zip(background_array, font_array)]  # Combine background and font styles
    else:
        return [''] * s.shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ; to seperate CSS properties.

```
def highlight_cells(s):
    if s.name=='a':
        conds = [s > 0, s < 0, s == 0]
        labels = ['background-color: lime; color: white', 'background-color: pink; color: white', 'background-color: gold']
        array = np.select(conds, labels, default='')
        return array
    else:
        return ['']*s.shape[0]

df.style.apply(highlight_cells).to_excel('df.xlsx', index=False)
```